# How to represent dimension-$(0,n)$ matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

In my code, I programmatically construct a `Dimensions` $(3,m)$ matrix, called `mtxA`.  I subsequently take its `Transpose`, forming an $(m,3)$ matrix, so that it can be dotted into a vector with $3$ elements.

But sometimes, $m$ is zero, which means `mtxA` looks like this :

```
mtxA = {{},{},{}};
Dimensions[mtxA]

(* {3, 0} *)
```

But now, if I take its `Transpose`, I get a wrong result:

```
Transpose[mtxA]
% // Dimensions

(* {} *)
(* {0} *)
```

Instead of a $(0,3)$ matrix, I have a $(0)$ vector.  And so when I try to `Dot` this into a 3-vector, I get a cascade of `Dot::dotsh` errors because you obviously can't dot `{}` into a 3-vector.

1. Is this because you can't represent a $(0,3)$ matrix in *Mathematica*?
2. Is it possible to tell `Transpose` to preserve the rank of my matrix?
3. How do I deal with this problem in my code without writing a bunch of `If` statements to treat the $m=0$ case separately?

Comment: What would a $(0, 3)$ matrix mean in this case? It'd have no elements, so the $3$ wouldn't make sense.

Comment: What would $m_{0 \times 3}  \cdot \mathbb{1}_{3 \times 1}$ return?

Comment: @Edmund It would return a $b_{0\times 1}$...  duh!  ;p

Comment: Perhaps you could cook something up by using `Null` for your zero dimension.  For example `m = {{Null}, {Null}, {Null}}` and then `Transpose@m . {{1}, {2}, {3}}` gives `{{6 Null}}` which you could, with `ReplaceAll`, get `{{Null}}` which you could in some way interpret as having dimension $0 \times 1$.  Seems a bit messy though.  Overall I think @user42582 has it correct in saying that it is not directly possible; until shown otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Dimensions` returns the appropriate dimensions for full arrays (see [Dimensions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html)). Executing `Depth[{}]` returns `2` which is interpreted as 'it takes 1 index to specify every possible level in expression `{}` (see [Depth](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Depth.html)). Also, `FullForm[{}]` returns (not surprisingly) `List[]`. Having said all that, it is my guess that it is not possible to define an expression in *Mathematica* with dimensions `{0,3}` because that would have to be interpreted as describing an expression that on level 1 has *no* parts while on level 2 there are 3 available parts, which sounds contradictory (to me).
2. I think `Transpose` (much like `Flatten`) cannot preserve the dimensions of arrays without full dimensions on all levels and an array like `{{},{},{}}` is one such case.
3. Unless there are more details, a single `If` checking the dimesions of `mtxA` might be sufficient; otherwise you could define two different functions eg `proc[mat_?(MatchQ[{{}, {}, {}}, #] &)]` and `proc[other_]` and let *Mathematica* decide which one it should call, depending on the input. The drawback of this approach is that you'd have to essentially duplicate much of the code that depends on `mtxA`.

Comment: There is no need to delete. Direct answer may be more suited for OP as duplicates don't need to match word by word.